# ApplicationListener is getting fired twice

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

This is firing twice does anyone know why:

```java
@Component
public class AuthenticationFailureListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private LoginAttemptService loginAttemptService;

    public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent e) {
        String email = (String) e.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        loginAttemptService.loginFailed(email);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is firing twice it is rgistered twice.

Comment: where would it be registered twice?

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot or a regular Spring application?

Comment: I am using Spring Boot

Comment: Then you have component scanning already and you might have added an `@Bean` method for this listener as well.